# Refactor .live() to .on() in SimpleSplitView

Tags: jquery, ipad

I'm attempting to use [**SimpleSplitView**](http://simplesplitview.sourceforge.net/) to render an iPad-like UI for a project I'm working on.  However, the example provided uses the deprecated jQuery API `.live()`:

```
$('#mainpage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('splitviewcontainer').padding = 44;
    $('#splitviewcontainer').simplesplitview();
});
```

jQuery deprecated `.live()` in 1.7 & removed it in 1.9, and my project is using 2.1.1.  Reading the documentation on [**the jQuery site**](http://api.jquery.com/live/), I should be able to refactor it to:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#mainpage", function (event) {
    document.getElementById('splitviewcontainer').padding = 44;
    $('#splitviewcontainer').simplesplitview();
});
```

However, when I try that with 2.1.1, I end up with the divs stacked on top of each other in the order they occur in the HTML, instead of in left & right orientation .  So I tried using `.on()` in 1.7.1 (which is what the original example uses), and I get the same stacked div results with the dev console complaining about an invalid function on that line.

In order to make this work, I *think* I need an event listener for the pageshow event, but I'm not sure how to implement that or if it's the right approach.

I tried to make a couple of fiddles to demonstrate the problem, but I can't get SimpleSplitView to work in JSFiddle at all (it just does the stacked view even using the original jQuery & JQM versions).

**The Question:**
What do I need to do to refactor `.live()` to `.on()` to make this work in current jQuery?